# Add child products of a product in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I have created a online shop for saree.. Now I want to add saree blouse and other details in product view page with its attribute... how will I do this?
[image]

Comment: you can create configurable products for this. you can check [link](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-create-configurable-product.html#gref) & [link2](https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-configurable-products-magento-ecommerce-site/) for more information.

Comment: do you want to sell "blouse" as separate products, or "Saree+ blouse" is one product ?

Comment: want to sell Saree+blouse is one product

Comment: is it possible by creating bundled or grouped product ?

Comment: i think for your requirement, `grouped product` is not going to work & i didt created bundled products much,  please check [here](https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/kbase/magento/magento-grouped-products.html)